# Why internet in not working on emulator on windows-XP but it shows 3G icon on emulator properly?

Tags: android

I have a problem with my android emulator, Internet is not access in it but it showing 3G icon. I read on many blogs they suggest to change the android-sdk I have done this but still it's not working. I also change the proxy settings and disabled the firewall but it's not working what could be the problem please suggest me.

Thanks....

Comment: sometimes restarting the emulator has worked for me.

Comment: I also restart it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution. In the case that your app requires Internet access you must add this permission to your Manifest file. Only then will internet access work for your application. The line should look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Make sure that this is in your application otherwise you will not be able to access the internet.